# my table dynamic layout keep appearing in the left side even the gravity is right

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout, android-tablelayout

what i am trying to do is to make a dynamic table layout .. i mean the rows will be filled dynamically with text views and with scrolling horizontal and vertical but each time when the activity open my table layout start showing from the left side even i set the gravity to be right .. why this is happening?

this is my xml code :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right" >
 <HorizontalScrollView
     android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
      <ScrollView
     android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
 <TableLayout 
     android:id="@+id/table1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:stretchColumns="0,1"
     android:layout_gravity="right" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 

            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_gravity="right">


        </TableRow>


    </TableLayout>
 </ScrollView>
 </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and here is my java code :

```
TableLayout ll = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table1);
int razan=0;
int c=-1;
    for(int s=1; s<=fixed;s++){
        if(razan<=count){
            for (int i = 0; i <text.length; i++) {

                if(i>0 && i%7==0){
                    c = c+1;
                    TableRow row1= new TableRow(this);
                    TableRow.LayoutParams tr1 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    row1.setLayoutParams(tr1);

                    TextView emptyrow = new TextView(this);
                    emptyrow.setText("");
                   // emptyrow.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.back));

                    row1.addView(emptyrow);


                    ll.addView(row1,i);
                }
                TableRow row= new TableRow(this);
                TableRow.LayoutParams tr = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                row.setLayoutParams(tr);

                TextView product = new TextView(this);
                TextView product_j = new TextView(this);


                product_j.setText(prodlist.get(razan));
                Resources res = getResources();

                Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.back);
                product_j.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);

                product_j.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                product_j.setTextSize(18);

                product.setText(text[i]);
             //   product.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
                product.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                product.setPadding(3, 0, 3, 0);
                product.setTextSize(18);
                row.addView(product_j);
                row.addView(product);

                razan++;
                ll.addView(row,i);
                //here is the code for adding an empty row after each seven inner rows !!!


            }//inner for

        }

}//outer fors

}
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: your table is not going in right???

Answer (score 0):

Make your root LinearLayouts Height and width as match_parent and try gravity to right on your TableLayout